# How do i join two tables in sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have two tables and I want to join them. I have similar column "mac" and later I want to return the row which is not present in the second table but present in first table. For clear view I have 10 rows in first table and 5 rows in second table I want to return only that 5 row which is not present in second column.

I am stuck with this.

I have tried a below query to join but it didn't work

Thanks in advance :)

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM " +MainActivity.collect+  "LEFT JOIN" +MainActivity.collect2+  "ON" +Coloumn.NewInfo.MAC+ "="+MAC+ null;
```

Comment: what does `didnt work` mean?

Comment: i am getting an error in that "="

Comment: log your `query` then

Comment: can u give me the working query for that ?

Comment: i dont think so,  what do you see when you log it?

Comment: SQLiteException: near "=": syntax error (code 1)

Comment: log the value of the `query` variable and watch the `logcat`, what do you see?

Comment: Are MainActivity.collect and MainActivity.collect2 variables storing table names? What does Coloumn.NewInfo.MAC mean and last but not least: what is the reason of the concatenated null at the end of the query?

Comment: you need to add spaces: " LEFT JOIN " and " ON "

Comment: @Bouke ya that storing a table name.coloumn.newinfo.mac is a cloumn name which is comming from a class coloumn and in coloumn there is a abstract class name newinfo.and even i don't know why null is for

Comment: Show me a picture of the table, that might help.

Answer (score 0):

you can do with stringFormat ,However I think your query is wrong ...

```
 String query = String.format("SELECT * FROM %s LEFT JOIN %s ON %s = %s ",
            MainActivity.collect,MainActivity.collect2 ,Coloumn.NewInfo.MAC,MAC);
```

%s is for String variable also , %d for integer , %f for float and ...